# Spring Rest Service GET with parentheses

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-rest

I have a Spring Rest Service like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/banks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<String> getBanks( @RequestParam(value="name" , required=true) String name)  {
...
}
```

The name must allows special character like parentheses, but the problem is that when i put parentheses on the param, y receive the ASCCI code like #040# on the "name" parameter.

I thought in use @RequestBody with a wrap filter like a posible solution, but the method must change to POST to support the wrap in the Request Body and the api design going to be bad.

So, someone have a solition for support parentheses on the param of a GET Rest Service?

Comment: I just tried your method and the name has parentheses. For "http://localhost:8080/banks?name=()" the value of name in `getBanks` method is "()"

Comment: Please post the cURL of the request you are making